# Better method for dynamically calling methods from input?

Tags: ruby, input, metaprogramming

Is it better to use case/when things or the send method when dynamically calling methods based on user input? "better" based primarily on good coding practices.

```
     input = gets.chomp
case input
when foo
    foo
when bar
    bar
end
```

versus

```
input = gets.chomp #Where hopefully the input would be 'foo' or 'bar'
send(input)
```

Comment: IMO "where hopefully the input would be..." is answering your own question. You can't guarantee that this will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Your wording makes the question incredibly hard to read.

If I understood you correctly, you want to call methods based on user input. One alternative would be to check every possible value and call a method, the other - to use `send` directly.

First of all, notice that in your first example, you were calling `method1` when the user entered `foo`. If you used `send(input)` you would have called `foo` instead. So they are not exactly the same.

You can achieve the same behavior by putting the *input->method* mapping in a hash like so:

```
dispatch = {foo: :method1, bar: :method2}
input    = gets.chomp.to_sym
send(dispatch[input])
```

Another thing to note is that `send` in the original situation would call any method passed. You can instead [whitelist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist) the possible methods with the hash above and checking if such value exists:

```
send(dispatch[input]) if dispatch.key? input
```

---

Now to the question of when to use one or the other:

1. If you have *2, 3, 5* or so possibilities, prefer explicitly listing them. It will be faster, easier to read, easier to do static code analysis and so on.
2. If you have hundreds and thousands of different methods, prefer `send`. The costs outweigh the benefits of being [*DRY*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
3. If the list of allowed methods is generated dynamically, you don't have a choice - use `send`. Examples:

   - You want to call methods to a given object and that object is different each time
   - You want to allow different methods depending on the user's permissions
   - You want to implement a [*REPL*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) or some other awesome tool that has extremely dynamic needs

In general, don't use meta programming, unless there is significant gain or you don't have any other choice.

Comment: Thank you for your help! QUestion is updated to hopefully be a little clearer (It was pretty late when this was asked).

Comment: @Chesshunter, so does this answer your question?

Comment: For the most part, yes. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you'd like your user to be able to call any method in the method lookup chain, including private methods which **send** can invoke, it probably makes sense for you to lock it down and only allow your users some methods.

If you don't specify an object to send to (like in your code above), Ruby will look at self for a method by that name and then use a normal method lookup. In other words **self** will be the first link in the method lookup chain. If you do specify an object, maybe an object that you create for that purpose for example, another option might be to use the methods like [**try**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.20/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) or [**respond_to?**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F).

Answer (score 0):

```
input = gets.chomp
if defined?(input.to_sym)
    send(input)
else
    puts "No such thing!"
```